# If kappa (Einstein's constant) depends on Lambda (cosmological constant), then why does kappa stay the same when Lambda is not null?

Tags: general-relativity, physical-constants, cosmological-constant

Regarding Einstein's constant (kappa):
[Einstein's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein's_constant)

It looks like it was solved based on the assumption the cosmological constant (Lambda) was null:
[calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein's_constant#Calculation)

But when Einstein considered Lambda to be not null then kappa never changed.  Was that a mistake from his part?

Comment: _The objection to this solution is that one has to introduce a negative pressure, for which there exists no physical justification. In order to make that solution possible I originally introduced a new member into the equation instead of the above-mentioned pressure, which is permissible from the point of view of relativity...The introduction of this second member constitutes a complication of the theory, which seriously reduces its logical simplicity. Its introduction can only be justified by the difficulty produced by the almost unavoidable introduction of a finite average density of matter_

Comment: A. Einstein - The Meaning of Relativity - Appendix 1 : On the "Cosmologic Problem"

Comment: The way out for $\Lambda$ (dismissal) was the discovery of universe expansion by Hubble, but it's way back in is the discovery of dark matter/energy.

Comment: *It looks like it was solved...* What does "it" refer to here? *If kappa (Einstein's constant) depends on Lambda (cosmological constant)...* Why would $\kappa$ depend on $\Lambda$? Please edit the question to clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda$ on the left side of the equations means cosmological constant. 
And the $\kappa$ on the right side of Einstein equations means gravitational constant $6.67408(31)\times 10^{−11} \text{m}^3 \cdot \text{kg}^{−1}\cdot \text{s}^{−2}$.

But often it is in General theory of relativity as G. 
You can solve Einstein equation without cosmological constant.
 But with right side with energy-impulse tensor.